# MySQL and gathering and counting information from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having issues figuring out how to do this. This isnt the real problem, but something very similar.

I have table A

```
ID  Name
10  Bob
11  Tom
12  Suzie
13  Billy
14  Rob
15  Ben
```

Then table B, where B_ID references to ID in table A

```
B_ID  Value
11    1500
13    2600
```

Then Table C where C_ID references to ID in table A

```
C_ID MatchedWith
10   11
12   13
14   11
15   11
```

The intention of this query is to list the Names of the people in table B, and how many people that are matched with them from C

...So the resulting query would give something like:

```
Name  Count
Tom   3
Bily  1
```

I am completely boggled on how to do this, so any help would be super! thank you!

Comment: I got it to work. I had not considered using joins before... still kind of new to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    A.Name,
    COUNT(*) as 'Count'
FROM 
    C
    JOIN B
    ON C.MatchedWith = B.B_ID
    JOIN A
    ON A.ID = B.B_ID
GROUP BY A.Name
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Comment: Wow quick reply! Your awesome!